# Prepend a div without the screen blinking

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

My question is similar to other questions, but with a twist.

I'm trying to inject a div as follows :

```
var headerDiv = document.getElementById("headerDiv");
if (headerDiv) {

    var logo = document.createElement('div');
    logo.id = "my-header";
    //logo.style.display = "none";

    var innerHTML = '   <div id="my-header-image"></div>' +
                    '   <div id="my-header-text">' +
                    '       My header text' + 
                    '   </div>  ';
    logo.innerHTML = innerHTML;
    headerDiv.insertBefore(logo, headerDiv.firstChild);     
}
```

headerDiv already previously exists in the page and renders well.
I'm calling my code only when the DOM is ready.

My problem is as follows : when the injection happens, **"logo" blits on the page as an entirely white div for a split second.** It's almost not noticeable if you don't look well. Then the style gets applied and everything goes back to normal.

It happens both in IE11 (IE10 mode or Edge mode) AND in **Chrome**.

**It didn't happen when I was using jQuery** instead of insertBefore.

Here is the CSS :

```
#my-header {
    pointer-events: none; /* the clicks must go through -- to the native Sharepoint buttons underneath. Required for Edge compatibility. */
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 50px; 
    overflow: auto;

    /* fade-in */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox < 16 */
    -ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
    -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
    animation: fadein 2s;
}

#my-header-text {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.0em;
}


#my-header-image {
    display:inline-block;
    content: "";

    top: 3px;
    left: 20px;
    width : 184px; /* same size as logo image */
    height : 38px;

    margin-top: 6px;
    background-image: url("https://MY_URL/logo.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-position: center center; 
}



/* fade-in animation definition */

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Could it be caused by the fade-in animation? The system doesn't know how to handle a new element that's supposed to start invisible (because of the animation) ?

I've noticed that "logo" blinks **above** "headerDiv" instead of **on top**, despite its absolute positionning. One more clue of some property being ignored in the early stage of rendering, between the time when the div gets added and the time when its style gets applied.

Comment: If it doesn't happen when you use jQuery, why don't you use jQuery then?

Comment: rblarsen : your question is off-topic. I hope it's not the reason why your downvoted my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it wth a dirty workaround :

In the JS :

```
...
var logo = document.createElement('div');
logo.id = "my-header";
logo.style.height = "0"; // <-- new
...
```

In the CSS :

```
#my-header {
    ...
    height: 50px !important; /* <-- made it important */
    ...
}
```

As you can understand, the object is forcefully made invisible and forced not to take up any on-screen space (by having height = 0) between the time of its creation by the JS and the time when the style gets applied by the CSS.

Therefore, the blinking still conceptually happens but its effect is not visible.